# gstreamer loop file naming?

Tags: gstreamer

I was able to succesfully generate a hsl stream with gstreamer, with the following code:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  \
               videotestsrc is-live=true \
               ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=2000000 control-rate=variable \
               ! "video/x-h264,profile=high,width=600,height=300" \
               ! mpegtsmux \
               ! hlssink \
               playlist-root=http://192.168.0.51:9000/hlssink/ \
               location=/home/attila/frontend/hlssink/hlssink.%05d.ts \
               max-files=5 \
               target-duration=10 \
               playlist-location=/home/attila/frontend/playlist.m3u8
```

It works very fine, but it has one flaw, the files genarated according to the property line of hlssink:

```
location=/home/attila/frontend/hlssink/hlssink.%05d.ts
```

are not looping. So the client should always relaod the playlist. How can I make gstreamer to loop through an iteration of file names?